# About image normalization prior to image segmentation

Tags: normalization, image-segmentation

I am trying to perform image segmentation on dermoscopy image using UNet. The image comes in as a RGB format with pixel range from 0-255.
My dataset shape is (200,256,256,3) where the first dim is the number of image and last dim is the colour channel.
Prior to segmentation, I use keras.utils.normalize (which I think it is L2 normalization) to normalize the image to 0-1 range. I tried to normalize the image at different axis. While some axis are able to provide a normal distribution, the pixel values after normalization are very small, mostly <0.1 and the image is barely visible on imshow. If I use the colour channel, the pixel values range is more diverse but it fails to achieve a normal distribution.
Wondering which axis of normalization should I pick?

Thank you:)[image]